# Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes

Tags: next.js

I literally did `npx create-next-app`, `cd appfolder`, `npm run dev`, and it's blowing out errors already:

```
(node:7636) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
error - ./styles/globals.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages\_app.js
```

Module list:

- eslint-config-next@11.1.1
- eslint@7.32.0
- next@11.1.1
- react-dom@17.0.2
- react@17.0.2

node -v = v14.17.5

Comment: Please, correct the formatting of the first line.

Comment: Remove the leading spaces in the first line. The first line is neither code nor screen output. As reader I do not want to have to scroll to the right to see the rest of your line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was experiencing the exact same issue as you described, and for what I’ve found, it seems to be due to a [breaking change](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28579) in `next@11.1.1` which is only affecting Windows.

Until this gets fixed, you can downgrade Next to version 11.1.0:

`npm install next@11.1.0`

`yarn add next@11.1.0`

Comment: You rock.   That actually fixed 3 different problems that I was having at the same time .....   I was getting the global CSS error, a MySQL error (from the MySQL test project) and "(node:5252) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API" which that fixed all of them in one shot.  They might want to roll back that code.  ;)  lol

Comment: @Mike hahahaa! Well, I’m quite glad that helped, and even more than I expected actually :)

Comment: Technically that is not a "breaking change", it is simply a bug (regression). It is fixed in `v11.1.2-canary.0` by [#28631](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/28631). If one doesn't want to use canary versions in production for obvious reasons, then they will have to wait till the fix makes its way to stable release.

Comment: [`v11.2.0` is now released.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.1.2) Just update Next.js to latest version in your project. It will fix the deprecation warning as well as the global css bug.

Comment: Well ... it was a change, forward or backward and it broke it.   So that's a breaking change by english definition.     Not using canary releases in production?   Oh, yea, I guess doing npx create-next-app leads straight to production.  ;)  lol