# Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
./styles/globals.scss
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. 
Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, 
Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. 
Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).

Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages/_app.tsx
```

[image]

And this error disappears when I commented out the following lines in the `_app.tsx`

```
// import "@styles/globals.scss";
```

[image]

But noticed that the stylesheet isn't being applied. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's the output of my `npm list`

```
 $ npm list --depth 0
├── @types/react@17.0.20
├── eslint-config-next@11.1.2
├── eslint@7.32.0
├── next@11.1.2
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react@17.0.2
├── sass@1.39.0
└── typescript@4.4.2
```

```
 $ npm list -g --depth 0
/Users/glaksmono/.nvm/versions/node/v16.8.0/lib
└── npm@7.22.0
```

Comment: as the errors says, move the import inside `_app.js`

Comment: Hi @Nico - the import is already inside `_app.tsx`, I tried to rename it to .js but then all of the ASX systax would be broken

Comment: Try creating css file in the root directory and import it like `import '../style.css'` in `_app.jsx`

Comment: @SandipNirmal still getting this error `event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
error - ./test.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages/_app.tsx`

Comment: since everything looks correct, can you try a clean restart once ? delete `node_modules`, `.next`, then do `npm i`, `npm run dev`

Comment: I did that multiple times, and I just did that again, still getting the same issue. Not exactly sure what's happening with my local @RGog

Comment: Hey @ZeusX I'm getting the same error too right now. Followed all the same steps and am still stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991702/fresh-nextjs-app-throwing-errors-before-any-changes)

Answer (score 4):

apparently there is a breaking change with `next@11.1.1` on windows. Downgrade to `next@11.1.0` to fix this issue.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68992114/12198209

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and I think the problem was that all of my code was being SmartSynced to Dropbox. As soon as I ran create-next-app in a folder that wasn't aliased into the Dropbox directory, everything worked fine. My suspicion is that Node/Webpack was seeing the wrong path because of the aliasing and that caused the error.