# next js create next app error when running npm run dev?

Tags: next.js

I initialized a project with create next app and when i run npm run dev i get this error:

> error - ./styles/globals.css
>
> Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom `<App>`. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
>
> Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
>
> Location: pages_app.js

this is my _app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68991702) -- Basically upgrade to v11.1.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

remove the import statement of the `CSS`.

```
import '../styles/globals.css' // Remove this

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

or add the `global.css` file inside the `styles` folder

You have moved/deleted the `CSS`, which causes this error.