# Why is Nextjs 11.1.1 throwing an error with my global scss file in _app.js after updating from Nextjs 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, next.js

I've had a project running on Nextjs 10 for the last year. I updated to Nextjs 11.1.1 and when I run "npm run dev" I get the following error:

```
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages\_app.js
```

I've read a lot about this issue already and the only global css import I have is in _app.js.
Here is my pared-down _app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'

export default function App() {
  <div> hello </div>
}
```

And my pared-down globals.scss:

```
.test{
  border:5px black;
}
```

And my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "cabbieadvocate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.0.0",
    "npm": "7.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    ".next/cache",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^2.22.1",
    "@uppy/core": "^2.0.2",
    "@uppy/react": "^2.0.2",
    "@uppy/xhr-upload": "^2.0.2",
    "bulma": "^0.9.2",
    "googleapis": "^73.0.0",
    "is-buffer": "^2.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "next": "11.1.1",
    "next-auth": "^3.20.1",
    "postmark": "^2.7.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.21",
    "react-visibility-detector": "^1.1.1",
    "react-visibility-sensor-v2": "^1.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "twilio": "^3.63.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-jose-tools": "^1.6.28",
    "prisma": "^2.22.1"
  }
}
```

This doesn't make any sense, please help.

Comment: can you share your `next.config.js` as well?

Comment: @ChemiAdel not using a custom config here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68991702) -- Basically upgrade to v11.1.2 or above.

Comment: @brc-dd good lord, yes. thank you. I feel like there should be some more loud kind of notification about this or they should remove v11.1.1 no?

Comment: @codyblanchard Actually a published version cannot be removed from NPM registry. They had published the patch within some hours to minimize the impact. Moreover this bug was only on Windows. They at first didn't test it.