# Import Global CSS file inside _app.js in next js throws error while building

Tags: css, import, next.js, global, build-error

So, I tried to import some **global style** in the **_app.js** component.

But when I build the code, I get the following error

[Screenshot of the error I get while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj8fz.png)

My next js **version ^11.1.2**

**Below is the code I implemented**

```
// _app.js file

import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

```
// globals.css file
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991702/) -- basically update your Next.js version.

Comment: No. And I already updated next js to the latest version (nextjs@^11.1.2).