# Fresh Nextjs app generates runtime errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do a fresh install of nextjs on Windows (see command line screenshot) using gitbash and latest nodejs lts version (16.14.2). When running `npm run dev` everything seems to be in order.

[image: command line output from install]

However, after browsing to `http://localhost:3000`, I receive this:

[image: browser response]

I looked at [Fresh NextJS App throwing errors before any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991702/fresh-nextjs-app-throwing-errors-before-any-changes) but the version in that issue is next `11.1.1` whereas current is `12.1.4`.  At this point I'm pretty much stuck. =\

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the same Next.js version. If you downgrade to a previous version, do you still get the error? Can you show us the output you get from running `npx next info`?

Comment: Since then I upgraded to the latest canary build with the same results.

```PS C:\Users\Owner\nextjs\my-demo> npx next info

    Operating System:
      Platform: win32
      Arch: x64
      Version: Windows 10 Pro
    Binaries:
      Node: 17.8.0
      npm: N/A
      Yarn: N/A
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:
      next: 12.1.5-canary.4
      react: 18.0.0
      react-dom: 18.0.0
```

Comment: Additionally, I experienced the same issue using the tutorial project with a new docker container using the official nodejs image.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with Chrome extensions.  I disabled all of them and no longer received the error.  One by one I re-enabled all of them but never found the source. =\